# Generating Unique Random Numbers in C++

Tags: c++, random

C++ beginner here. And I have this code below. It's more than that but this is the part where I need help. I need to generate random numbers( 0 - 9 )and push it back into a vector. And I want those random numbers to be unique. How do I do that?
Also, I cannot use the std::find(std::begin(vector),std::end(vector),a).
Thank you all so much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  int digit = 0;
  int randNo = 0;
  cin >> digit;       
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
  vector <int> randG(digit);
            for(int i = 0; i < randG.size(); i++){
                    randNo = rand() %10;
                    randG.at(i) = randNo;
            }
  }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: The common solution to this is to use the Fisher-Yates Shuffle. An example of how to do this in C++ can be found at the bottom of [this documentation page for `std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: I don't think my teacher allows me to use that. Sorry. Can you tell me how to do it using simple for or while loops? Thank you.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, `shuffle()` being the most idiomatic. But as you are just starting off in C++ but know about `vector` one simple, if inefficient, approach is to get a random number between 0 and 9. Test whether it exists in your vector. If not `push_back` that number. Repeat until all 10 numbers are in your vector. A better approach is to create a vector of tuples with the first elements ranging from 0 to 9 and plop a random number in the second. Then sort the vector against the second. Much more efficient. Just approaches to learn from. Then do Fisher-Yates.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about efficiency, and you want to sample uniformly without replacement from {a,a+1,...,b} you can create a `vector<int> vstart` where `vstart[i]=a+i`. After that, if you want k samples and store them  in `v_samples`, generate a random number `numrand` in [0,`v.size()`) , push `vstart[numrand]` into `vsamples`, and delete the sampled entry from `vstart` ( deleting corresponds to the "without replacement" part), repeating this k times. deleting might be costly so shuffling `vstart` and picking the first k entries of the shuffled vector.

Be careful when shuffling, as you might not get a uniform shuffle: https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/2744-how-not-to-shuffle-the-kunth-fisher-yates-algorithm.html. The best approach is to use the shuffle function in the `<algorithm>` library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/, or to program a verified shuffle yourself (Knuth shuffle is the classic solution to this problem).